# how to style wordpress links according to state. if active it should be a different style

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a Elementor mega menu with custom text links. these links go to different product pages. now i want the active link (actual page im on) to be styled differently and it seems that there is no easy option to do that in wordpress.

So if the link on a page matches the url it should be highlighted in CSS.

i tried this so far, but it didn't work:

```php
function highlight_current_page_link() { ?>
    <style>
    .current-page-link {
        /* Change the style of the current page link here */
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        jQuery("a").each(function() {
            var linkURL = jQuery(this).attr("href");
            if (linkURL == currentURL) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("current-page-link");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'highlight_current_page_link');
```

Comment: _"and it seems that there is no easy option to do that in wordpress"_ - WordPress usually handles adding relevant classes itself already, including some to highlight the currently active menu item and its parents. Are you saying there are no such classes present on the generated HTML elements?